qtwidgetsglobals.h file not found
I am trying to install and use Qt6 on my system but have run into issues. Here's my setup:
OS: KDE Neon (Ubuntu-based)
Processor: Intel i5, 5th generation
RAM: 8 GB

I installed Qt6 using the following commands:
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev  

I included all dependencies as prompted during installation. However, when I try to run any Qt6 applications using the new Zed IDE, i get an error, clang: In included file: 'QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h' file not found'. If I try using Qt Creator, it says, no kits are available
